# ember 2.0: use same controller in several routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-controllers

How to specify which controller to use in a route in ember 2.0?
Default is that each route has its own controller and if I don't have code for a controller then a default empty controller is generated at runtime.

I want to specify that several routes share the same controller (and model). I see that in the [documentation to an older version](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/setting-up-a-controller/) of ember it is possible to specify the controller with the "controllerName" property in the routes definition but that part of the documentation has been removed for the lastest ember version. And when I test the controllerName property it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you could use inheritance and/or mixins to share the same logic across several controllers

Comment: Can you share more details about the logic that you're trying to share amongst routes?

Comment: I solved my own question. Se answer below.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly what you are looking for but you could extend the controller that you want to use on the other routes.

```
import FooIndexController from 'ember-app/foo/index/controller';
export default FooIndexController.extend({});
```

You may also consider a mixin if you have a lot of code that should be shared by many controllers. It can be a much cleaner solution.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import BaseController from 'ember-app/mixins/base-controller';
export default Ember.Controller.extend(BaseController, {
    // Code specific to _this_ controller lives here
});
```

Comment: Thanx. That makes sense. Not what I was looking for right now, but those tricks might also become useful.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It turns out `controllerName` does work after all.

I just did this:

```
// route/home/books/book/details
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    controllerName: "home/books/book/index",
});
```

Then `book` and `book/details` shares controller. They already share model because the `details` route is a sub-route of `book`. So it works nicely.